# Restrict users to read exclusively one's own articles

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the following article_detail view which restrict that only users logged in could read the details.

```
@login_required(login_url="/user/login/")
def article_detail(request, pk):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
    total_views = r.incr("article:{}:views".format(article.id))
    page_number = request.GET.get('page_number', 1)
    #mimic SO's 100 per-page
    per_page = request.GET.get("per_page", 30)
    ....
```

How could I set that each user can exclusively read contents posted by oneself?

The article model

```
class Article(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (1,  'normal'),
        (0, 'deleted'),
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField() # set the widget
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-date_created",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: How is `Article` modeled?

Comment: You're requirement is at the `/admin` page??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one more criteria (owner) in your query:

```
article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk, owner=request.user)
```

If the request user is *NOT* the article owner, then `404` will be returned.

You can also return `403` permission denied error with following codes which is more meaningful to the client:

```
from from django.http.response import HttpResponseForbidden

article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
if article.owner.pk != request.user.pk:
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
... # permission checking pass, so other code goes here
```